# How to show values from map or list made in controller class with Phoenix

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm trying to create radio button. I know how to radio button following way.

```
  <%= label f, :gender_id %>
  <%= radio_button f, :gender_id, 1, checked: true %> Male
  <%= radio_button f, :gender_id, 2 %> Female
  <%= radio_button f, :gender_id, 0 %> Other
```

On the other hand, I don't know how to show title. I don't have genders model in framework.
I just want to create by gender map or list like following way.

```
<%= gender[1] %>   # Male
<%= gender[2] %>   # Female
<%= gender[0] %>   # Other
```

How can I create some gender list or map in controller?

Please let me know some advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is stated in docs, [`Phoenix.HTML.Form.radio_button/4`](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_html/Phoenix.HTML.Form.html?#radio_button/4) creates the radio button itself, while [`Phoenix.HTML.Form.label/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_html/Phoenix.HTML.Form.html#label/2) creates a label for it. That said, you might do something like below, assuming the respective assign is declared in the controller.

```rb
# controller
@genders %{0 => "other", 1 => "male", 2 => "female"}
render(conn, "page.html", genders: @genders)
# or put it to assigns

# template
<% for {id, label} <- @genders do %>
  <%= radio_button f, :gender_id, id, checked: id == 1 %>
  <%= label f, :gender_id, id, do: label %>
<% end %>
```